# TimeZoneInfo problem between Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: c#, linux, windows, github-actions, nunit

Please see the following C# test:

```cs
using FluentAssertions;
using FluentAssertions.Extensions;

namespace Tests.Unit.Api;

[TestFixture]
[Category("Unit")]
public class Tests
{
    [TestCase(1953,4,12,"21:53")] // fails
    [TestCase(1953,2,12,"20:53")] // succeeds
    [TestCase(2023,4,12,"21:53")] // succeeds
    [TestCase(2023,2,12,"20:53")] // succeeds
    public void WhyDoesThisFail(int year, int month, int day, string expectedTime)
    {
        // Arrange
        var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Europe/Berlin");
        var dateTime = new DateTime(year,month,day,19,53,3,DateTimeKind.Utc);

        // Act
        var result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dateTime, timeZoneInfo);

        // Assert
        TimeOnly.FromDateTime(result).ToShortTimeString().Should().Be(expectedTime);
    }
}
```

When running this test on my Win11 machine both in Rider and Visual Studio or via `dotnet test`, it succeeds without issues.

But within my GitHub Action running on `Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS`, it fails with:

```bash
  Failed WhyDoesThisFail [2 ms]
  Error Message:
   Expected TimeOnly.FromDateTime(result).ToShortTimeString() to be "21:53", but "20:53" differs near "0:5" (index 1).
```

I already figured out that it seems to be related to daylight savings, but I'd like know...

1. Why does it happen?
2. How can I stabilize this code without introducing any platform-specifics?

Thx!

Running on .NET `7.0.305`

Comment: Would utilizing NodaTime be an option for you?

Comment: Maybe, but to be honest, I don't want to switch to any third-party code before understanding why the problem occurs at all

Comment: I am not 100% sure neither, but the implementations for the date calculations may be based on different systems in windows and Linux. I am not even sure which value is correct, from the top of my head because I don't know if dst was in effect in 1953 for that tz.

Comment: It seems Europe had summer time from the end of the 19th century, but with varying regulations. Also, the modern time zones don't necessarily match historic ones. For instance, Switzerland is now part of the CEST area, but was not using summer time until 1981.

Comment: Very interesting! I've updated my question with more test cases and as you can see, only the very first one fails on Ubuntu (on Win11 still all green).

Comment: @mu88 I'm not sure this plays a role, but consider setting a culture (eg. "de-DE" or "de-CH") explicitly for the text.

Comment: Setting the culture that does not help, unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/discussions/88945) and here's the response:

> When I look at `timeZoneInfo.GetAdjustmentRules()` for `Europe/Berlin` on Windows, I see:
>
> ```
> Rule valid: 1. 1. 0001 0:00:00 - 31. 12. 9999 0:00:00
> DST period: Sunday, 5. week in 3. month at 02:00:00 - Sunday, 5. week in 10. month at 03:00:00
> DST delta: 01:00:00
> ```
>
> I.e. Windows simplifies things and assumes that time zone always followed its current DST rules.
>
> On the other hand, on Linux (which uses the tzdb), there is no DST adjustment rule between 1949 and 1980, which seems to be correct (Germany did not observe DST during this period).
>
> So the Windows result is incorrect, but there's not much .Net can do about that, since it just takes the data from Windows.